# Shrink split TFS 2017.u1 collections

Tags: tfs

I've recently split my main collection into two collections (A and B) where A contains all of team projects we're actively working on and B containing all of the projects we no longer use.  A contains about 10 team projects, B contains about 5.  I followed the instructions for splitting the collection in this article: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/tfs-server/admin/split-team-project-collection

Prior to the split, our database was about 33Gb.  After the split, as I understand it, the sum of both databases (after shrinking) should be about the same.  Instead, we have two databases about 33Gb.

I've looked over this thread (https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/804226/collection-database-size-is-not-reduced-after-destroy-large-files-or-completely-delete-team-projects) and I can see that I that B has about 25k files to delete and A has about 100k.

I've tried running:

```
EXEC prc_DeleteUnusedContent @partitionId = 1
EXEC prc_DeleteUnusedFiles  1, 0, 10
```

And that freed up maybe 2-3GB of space on each, but there should be a lot more freed up.  The majority of my data is in tbl_content (appox 28464856 KB in database B).    SQL is reporting A has about 3 gigs of free space, and B has about 4.  I'd expect these numbers to be closer to 10-15.

I feel like I'm missing something simple.

Answer (score 0):

Please note that the metadata and files will not get cleaned up immediately when you delete the original projects, since TFS do that sort of work in the background. Check that after 7 days as the solution described [here](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/118099/reduce-tfs-database-size-after-deleting-almost-all.html).

If you want to force it, you can run the the commands you mentioned above against the relevant collection DB:

```
EXEC prc_CleanupDeletedFileContent 1

EXEC prc_DeleteUnusedFiles 1, 0, 10
```

According to your description, the commands are effective.

But please note that the chunksize `10` in that second command is the batch size, so if your repository contains more than that number of files you may need to **run the command multiple times**. Or just as Daniel said in the link you mentioned :  If you feel that it ran fast enough, you can **increase this number**.
eg: `EXEC prc_DeleteUnusedFiles 1, 0, 100000`

Also note that this may take care of itself in a couple of days in the background.

Besides, you can also clean test attachments. Reference:[When to use the Test Attachments Cleaner (and when not)](https://blogs.msmvps.com/vstsblog/2014/03/07/when-to-use-the-test-attachments-cleaner-and-when-not/)

And below  articles to analyse and shrink the database for your reference:

- [Need Help: TFS tbl_Content Table and Database growth out of
  control](https://mattyrowan.com/2014/04/02/need-help-tfs-tbl_content-table-and-database-growth-out-of-control/)
- [Cleaning up and reduce the size of the TFS database](https://gyorgybalassy.wordpress.com/2014/04/02/cleaning-up-and-reduce-the-size-of-the-tfs-database/)

Comment: That was a typo - I was doing it by 1000.  Today, I tried again and it took a few moments and it clear out a few hundred and then went back to returning instantly.  

The test attachment cleaner is for tfs 2015.  Will that work with 2017?

Comment: @ChristopherC. PowerTool i's for VS 2015, not available for VS 2017, you can use VS 2015 to connect to TFS 2017 If possible. Have you tried other methods mentioned in above answer? Is that work for you?

Comment: I've tried the CleanupDeletedFileContent and DeleteUnusedFiles.  Sometimes it seems like it runs, delete a few files and then all subsequent runs are really fast.  Right now it's running and is taking some time.  Not sure if that's a good sign or not but I'm going to let it run it's course.

As I've read it, the 2015 test attachment cleaner will not work with 2017 as the structure changed and I'm not testing this out on my production instance.

Comment: @ChristopherC. Is that working? have you resolved the issue?

Comment: After a while, the count became 0 but it still doesn't show a lot of free space in the database.  I'm just going to deal with it for now.